# Does Ruby safe navigation operator evaluate its parameters when its receiver is nil?

Tags: ruby, safe-navigation-operator

#### Question:

**Does Ruby safe navigation operator (`&.`) evaluate its parameters when its receiver is `nil`?**

For example:

```
logger&.log("Something important happened...")
```

- Is the `"Something important happened..."` string evaluated here?
- Could you provide an authoritative source, which proves or denies this fact?
- Or suggest a way how to check it?

Thanks in advance.

#### Why I am looking for an answer to this question?

I have the code like the following throughout my codebase:

```rb
logger.log("Something important happened. (#{Time.current})") if verbose
```

My main goal is to remove the repetition of the `if verbose` check whenever I call the `log` method since it is easy to forget about it and you will be not notified at all about the misusage.

Inspired by the [Tell, don't ask](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tell-dont-ask) principle,

I have moved `if verbose` check inside `log` method implementation.

```rb
class Logger
  # ...
  
  def log(message)
    return unless verbose

    # ...
  end
end

def logger
  @logger ||= Logger.new
end

logger.log("Something important happened. (#{Time.current})")
```

This approach simplified my code since I have solved my main problem - I don't need to remember to place `if verbose` whenever I call the `log` method,

but I have received another issue.

`"Something important..."` string is always evaluated, no matter whether `verbose` is `true` or `false`.

Therefore, I have completely changed the solution:

- `logger` returns `nil` when `verbose` is `false`.
- Ruby safe navigation operator should be used in front of `log` calls.

```rb
def logger
  @logger ||= Logger.new if verbose
end

logger&.log("Something important happened. (#{Time.current})")
```

As a result, I have replaced the initial problem of remembering `if verbose` checks to remembering of `&.` calls.

But, anyway, I consider this as an improvement, since forgetting to utilize the safe navigation operator raises the `NoMethodError`, in other words, notifies about the `log` method misusage.

So now, in order to be sure that the 'safe navigation operator approach' is actually a 'better' option for my problem,

I need to know exactly whether the safe navigation operator in Ruby evaluates its parameters when its receiver is `nil`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote from [the syntax documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator) for the safe navigation operator:

> `&.`, called “safe navigation operator”, allows to skip method call when receiver is `nil`. **It returns `nil` and doesn't evaluate method's arguments if the call is skipped.**

As such, the arguments of your `log` method are not evaluated if the `logger` is `nil` when you call it as

```
logger&.log("something happened at #{Time.now}")
```

---

With that being said, note that the Ruby core logger offers a different solution to your exact issue, namely to avoid having to evaluate potentially expensive arguments if the log level is to high.

The Ruby core logger implements its `add` method something like this (simplified):

```
class Logger
  attr_accessor :level

  def initialize(level)
    @level = level.to_i
  end

  def add(severity, message = nil)
    return unless severity >= level
    
    message ||= yield
    log_device.write(message)
  end

  def info(message = nil, &block)
    add(1, message, &block)
  end
end
```

You can then use this as

```
logger = Logger.new(1)
logger.info { "something happened at #{Time.now}" }
```

Here, the block is only evaluated if the log level is high enough that the message is actually used.

Answer (score 3):

### Expression Parsed But Not Executed

The argument to `logger&.log` isn't evaluated when `logger.is_a?(NilClass) == true`. Every Ruby expression that's evaluated should have an impact, so consider:

```
test = 1
nil&.log(test+=1); test
#=> 1
```

If the argument were evaluated by the interpreter, *test* would equal two. So, while the parser certainly *parses* the expression in your argument, it doesn't *execute* the inner expression.

You can verify what the parser sees with [Ripper#sexp](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html#method-c-sexp):

```
require 'ripper'

test = 1
pp Ripper.sexp "nil&.log(test+=1)"; test
```

> ```
> [:program,
>  [[:method_add_arg,
>    [:call,
>     [:var_ref, [:@kw, "nil", [1, 0]]],
>     [:@op, "&.", [1, 3]],
>     [:@ident, "log", [1, 5]]],
>    [:arg_paren,
>     [:args_add_block,
>      [[:opassign,
>        [:var_field, [:@ident, "test", [1, 9]]],
>        [:@op, "+=", [1, 13]],
>        [:@int, "1", [1, 15]]]],
>      false]]]]]
> #=> 1
> ```

This clearly shows that the parser sees the incremented assignment in the symbolic expression tree. However, the assignment is never actually executed.

Comment: Your test only shows that *this particular version* of *this particular implementation* will, for *this particular piece of code* not evaluate the expression. There is no guarantee that a future version of a different Ruby implementation for a different piece of code behave the same. Hence, why the OP is asking for a quote from a spec or official documentation instead of an example. Examples, by their very nature, can *never* prove anything, they can only *disprove*, in the form of a counter-example. This is similar to how tests can never prove that code is bug-free, they can only prove bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It does not evaluate them:

```
require 'pry'

logger = nil
logger&.log(binding.pry)
```

This returns:

```
nil
```

If it evaluated it then it would trigger the binding like this example does:

```
a = []
a&.push(binding.pry)
```

If you don't have pry but do have a modern version of Ruby you can substitute `binding.irb` for `binding.pry`.

Whether or not this is a "better" solution is something you should benchmark to be sure.

You can read more about the safe navigation operator at [How is the Ruby safe navigation (&.) implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51818060/3784008)

Comment: Your test only shows that *this particular version* of *this particular implementation* will, for *this particular piece of code* not evaluate the expression. There is no guarantee that a future version of a different Ruby implementation for a different piece of code behave the same. Hence, why the OP is asking for a quote from a spec or official documentation instead of an example. Examples, by their very nature, can *never* prove anything, they can only *disprove*, in the form of a counter-example. This is similar to how tests can never prove that code is bug-free, they can only prove bugs.

Answer (score 1):

No, and it's very easy to test:

```
$ irb
> def test
>   puts 'triggered!'
> end
 => :test 
> def nothing
> end
 => :nothing 
> nothing&.whatever(test)
 => nil
> nothing&.whatever("string_#{test}")
 => nil
```

Conceptually you might think of safe navigation operator as this:

```
x&.test(param) # is "conceptually" equal to

if x.respond_to?(:test)
  x.test(param)
end

# or, as pointed in the comment: 
unless x.nil?
  x.test(param)
end
```

And now it's pretty clear why it's not evaluated when it's not called.

Comment: Your first example is not conclusive (since it doesn't differ whether `test` would be called or not) and your conceptional explanation is wrong (since `&.` only tests whether the receiver is `nil`) and slightly misleading (since you can not emulate the full behavior of the safe-navigation operator in pure Ruby, specifically because it does evaluate method arguments if the receiver is `nil`.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the code. And, if you look closely, I wrote "conceptually". I can update that part as well...

Comment: Your test only shows that *this particular version* of *this particular implementation* will, for *this particular piece of code* not evaluate the expression. There is no guarantee that a future version of a different Ruby implementation for a different piece of code behave the same. Hence, why the OP is asking for a quote from a spec or official documentation instead of an example. Examples, by their very nature, can *never* prove anything, they can only *disprove*, in the form of a counter-example. This is similar to how tests can never prove that code is bug-free, they can only prove bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the specific question, as that has already been answered, but is instead an alternative in light of the stated goal.

Ruby's Logger already has a block syntax, where the block is only evaluated *iff* the log level would print the statement.

```
logger.debug { puts "Do not evaluate this!"; "My String" }
```

If the log level is debug or higher, then the block will be evaluated, and the string it returns will be logged.  If the log level is less than debug the statement will not be evaluated at all.

TL;DR: Pass expensive log statements to your logger inside blocks.